# Select Colored cells and fill with

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I tried to write a macro with VBA on excel, but failed since this is my first try of VBA.

Can you help me to write a function which selects cells with a specific color(RGB 204 255 255) and fills/replaces them with consequential numbers? I need it fast.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the code your currently using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub AssignValues()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.Interior.Color = RGB(205, 255, 255) Then
            r.Value = i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a saint @Gary's Student. +1 for taking on a demanding questioner.